# Не выводится prompt value

Tags: javascript, html

Почему мне пишется,что 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

Я пытаюсь сделать так,чтобы внутри h3 тага, было введённое значение.

Index.html

```
   <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/JavaScript; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>JavaScript</title>
<script src="./index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border=2 bordercolor="Red">
        <tr>
            <td width="500" height="100">
                <button onclick="DocLoad()">Ccылка на странице</button>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="250" height="250">
                <iframe name="124"></iframe>
                <td width="250" height="250">
                    <iframe name="123"></iframe>
                </td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>



</script>
</body>
```

DocOK2.HTML

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/JavaScript; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript</title>

</head>
<body>
<h3 id="secret"></h3>
<script src="./index.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function DocLoad(){
    var ret1 = prompt("Введите ваше имя");

    if ((ret1) == "Саша"){
     window.open("./blue.jpg","124")
    } else if(ret1 !== "Саша" && ret1 !== ""){
        window.open("./DocOK2.html","123");
        document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = ret1;
    }       
};
```

v1

```
function DocLoad(){
    var ret1 = prompt("Введите ваше имя");
    var newWin = window.open("./DocOK2.html","123");

    if ((ret1) == "Саша"){
     window.open("./blue.jpg","124")
    } else{
        newWin.onload = function(){ 
        newWin.document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = ret1;
    };
    }       
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var newWin = window.open("./DocOK2.html","123");
    newWin.onload = function(){ 
      newWin.document.getElementById("secret").innerHTML = ret1;
    };
```

Comment: Отредактировал исходное сообщение.Не работает